# Displaying other columns from the related foreign key table mvc3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table called **Rubrique** with attributes **code** ,**type, libellé** and **rubriqueID** as a **foreign key** for the table **Rubriqueintermediare** which have just **Rubriqueid and RubriqueIntremediareID** as attributes . I want to display the code and the libellé of the rubrique in the rubriqueintermediare view: to be specified the wiew of the rubriqueintermediare is composed froim the two field (code and libellé )of the table rubrique . I just know the select list but it show me just one field I want to display  more columns from the related foreign key table. Is that possible??How to do it?